# How can I obtain an online libretto in Russian for the opera Boris Godunov?

Tags: opera

The Met Opera has been showing "Boris Godunov" in its daily streamings.

I'd be interested in an online version of the libretto in the original Russian, but seem unable to locate one.

Comment: In case you need something to do during the intermission: [Boris Badenov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syBRZGU95aA)

Answer (score 6):

By "original Russian," I assume you mean one using Russian/Cyrillic script?

If so, for cases like this I find it's easier to search the title in the original language. Thus an Internet search for "boris godunov libretto" may not find what you're looking for, but using some high-level sleuthing (that is, Wikipedia), you can replace "boris godunov" with "Борис Годунов."

Doing so sent me pretty quickly to [this link](http://operaibalet.ru/boris-godunov), which has the full libretto a bit lower on the page.

If a transliterated version is fine, then "boris godunov libretto" served me well enough; I found [this](http://opera.stanford.edu/iu/libretti/borisrus.html) on the first page of search results.

Answer (score 5):

The Russian libretto for *Boris Godunov* (which is to say, "Борис Годунов") is available online here: http://musorgskiy1839.narod.ru/boris.htm.

Full scores and parts are [available on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Boris_Godunov_(Mussorgsky,_Modest)).